# RNotebook cannot output due to html_dependency not found

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

I have had trouble getting R to output any work from the notebook.  I have updated all packages and reinstalled R.  I try to preview and the error message I receive is "path for html_dependency not found".  I believe this problem could be related to the failure of my file to create a .nb.html file with the .Rmd file but I am unsure.
The method I have used to try to insure that it was not user error is opening a brand new session and notebook and trying to output the already written script.
Any ideas?

Edit:
Here is my code which is the base notebook code:
    ---
    title: "R Notebook"
    output: html_notebook
    ---

````
This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. When you 
execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code. 

Try executing this chunk by clicking the *Run* button within the chunk or by 
placing your cursor inside it and pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. 

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

Add a new chunk by clicking the *Insert Chunk* button on the toolbar or by 
pressing *Ctrl+Alt+I*.

When you save the notebook, an HTML file containing the code and output will 
be saved alongside it (click the *Preview* button or press *Ctrl+Shift+K* to 
preview the HTML file).
````

I have it saved as test notebok.Rmd but cannot get a .nb.html file to create itself I believe is the problem.

Comment: The best thing would be for you to add as much of your file as possible on here. That way, diagnosis would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but for knit to HTML, after trying everything I ended up uninstalling and deleting everything and re-installing It all. This worked for me, simply updating the software didn't